# Finding gaps or overlaps in ranges

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose I had a table with the following format:

```
|               dbo.ROUTES               |
 ----------------------------------------
| ID | ROUTE | LOWER_LIMIT | UPPER_LIMIT |
 ----------------------------------------
|  0 |   A   |       0     |     10      |
|  1 |   B   |      11     |    500      |
|  2 |   C   |     600     |   1000      |
```

How could I find any number ranges that aren't covered by a route entry? i.e. For the example above, I would need to be able to see that there is no entry that covers 501 - 599.

We're currently using this layout, albeit with 4 or 5 other columns with various criteria, and we've found that (as you'd expect) as the table has both grown, and had the lower and upper thresholds updated, we're starting to see voids and overlaps.

I know this really falls down to poor design, but until we have the resources to improve it, we could do with something in the interim that could at least help us tidy the tables manually.

Thanks,

Comment: Which version of SQL Server?

Comment: 2008 R2 at the moment.

Comment: @king.code why do you ask?

Comment: @Yuck to know if he can use `LEAD` and `LAG` functions.

Comment: cool! i didnt know about either one!

Comment: They both look very useful indeed, I wish I'd known about then in my previous job. I'd be interested in knowing the performance costs too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can not use lead/lag functions, i have used alternate way to achieve this. Edit boundary conditions in output columns (missing_val, overlapping) as per your need by adding/subtracting 1

Input:

```
ID  LOWER_LIMIT UPPER_LIMIT

0   0   10
1   11  500
2   600 1000
3   980 1100
```

Output:

```
ID  LOWER_LIMIT UPPER_LIMIT MISSING_VAL OVERLAPPING

0   0   10      0   0
1   11  500 500-600 0
2   600 1000    0   980-1000
3   980 1100    0   0
```

Query :

```
SELECT ID, LOWER_LIMIT, UPPER_LIMIT, CASE WHEN 
UPPER_LIMIT+1=NEXT_LOWER_VAL THEN '0' 
WHEN UPPER_LIMIT+1< NEXT_LOWER_VAL THEN
UPPER_LIMIT||'-'||NEXT_LOWER_VAL ELSE '0' END AS MISSING_VAL,
CASE WHEN 
UPPER_LIMIT+1= NEXT_LOWER_VAL THEN '0' 
 WHEN UPPER_LIMIT+1> NEXT_LOWER_VAL THEN NEXT_LOWER_VAL||'-'||UPPER_LIMIT ELSE '0' END AS       OVERLAPPING
FROM 
(
SELECT T1.*, (SELECT MIN(LOWER_LIMIT) FROM TEST_T T WHERE T.ID<> T1.ID AND T.LOWER_LIMIT>     T1.LOWER_LIMIT) AS NEXT_LOWER_VAL
FROM TEST_T T1) SUB
```

Comment: Can you explain the meaning of `||`? SSMS returns `incorrect syntax near |` Is there a reason you aren't just casting as varchar and concatenating?

Comment: || is oracle syntax to concat column values. You can change it as per your database.  Also if you don't want values to be like "980-1000", you can create two columns (overlap_start_val, overlap_end_val) with values 980, 1000. Oracle handles (converting number values to  string, "980-1000") internally very well. I would say you should go with creating two columns only instead of concatenation so that you can query your resultset easily.

Answer (score 0):

This should show rows that have gaps on either side of it:

```
SELECT * FROM ROUTES 
WHERE NOT Exists(SELECT ID FROM ROUTES as sub
 WHERE sub.Lower_Limit = ROUTES.Upper_Limit + 1)
OR NOT Exists(SELECT ID FROM ROUTES as sub1
 WHERE sub1.Upper_Limit = ROUTES.Lower_Limit - 1)
```

Comment: This gives nothing but the content of the ROUTES table.

Comment: This works if you switch direction of the increments - (lower_limit would be `upper_limit + 1` and upper_limit would be `lower_limit -1`). I had to add high and low bounds too, to prevent it returning the very first and last rows.

Comment: @Rono this still gives everything!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using SQL Server 2008 you can't use `LEAD` and `LAG` functions, you need a self join:

```
SELECT T2.UPPER_LIMIT + 1 AS R1
      ,T1.LOWER_LIMIT - 1 AS R2
FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID) AS RID
            ,ID
            ,ROUTE  
            ,LOWER_LIMIT
            ,UPPER_LIMIT
      FROM ROUTES) AS T1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID) AS RID
                 ,ID
                ,ROUTE  
                ,LOWER_LIMIT
                ,UPPER_LIMIT
           FROM ROUTES) AS T2
    ON T1.RID = T2.RID + 1
WHERE T1.LOWER_LIMIT - T2.UPPER_LIMIT > 1;
```

In SQL Server 2012+:

```
SELECT LAG_UPPER_LIMIT + 1 AS R1
      ,LOWER_LIMIT     - 1 AS R2
FROM (SELECT ID
            ,ROUTE  
            ,LOWER_LIMIT
            ,UPPER_LIMIT
            ,LAG(UPPER_LIMIT) OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS LAG_UPPER_LIMIT
      FROM ROUTES) AS T
WHERE T.LOWER_LIMIT - T.LAG_UPPER_LIMIT > 1
```

This gives you exactly the missing ranges.

Comment: This looks very promising, let me test and get back to you.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name that is correct. In fact I provided two different versions: one for SQL Server 2012+ and one for previous versions.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for are `upper_limit` values that don't overlap with anything along with the next `lower_limit` value.  Actually, you want one more than the upper limit value and one less than the next lower limit value:

```
select r.upper_limit + 1 as missing_lower,
       (select min(lower_limit) - 1
        from routes r3
        where r3.lower_limit > r.upper_limit + 1
       ) as missing_higher
from routes r
where not exists (select 1
                  from routes r2
                  where r.upper_limit + 1 between r2.lower_limit and r2.upper_limit
                 );
```